# How do you link to a page within a facebook iframe?

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-like

For example, I have the application starting at index.php. The user navigates to about.php within the iframe, likes that specific page and shares it. What would the structure of the url look like to take people clicking from their own timeline into that page of my iframe?

Thanks!

Comment: It actually did work - much easier than I thought it was going to be. I think my problem now lies in the fact that I'm running a tab application instead of just a purely canvas app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends, if you are on a FanPage it does not work (directly)

on a App Page its easy. You simpley dont link relative in your iframe, but outside to the facebook page itself, for this to work your Canvas url needs to be a directory.

Then you can link to ie. http://apps.facebook.com/yourcanvas/about.php (dont forget the target _top)

On a FanPage the only way i know is to use beside the tab setting, a canvas app page.

in your share code you set the app page as target (with parameter) and on the app page you set a session variable for the desired target and then redirect back to the fanpage. 
on the fanpage you look if you have an target value in your session, if so redirect the user.